# Determine hostname of device given private ip address

Tags: networking, ip, lan, hostname

I've found out that if I ping my broadcast ip address I get a response of all the devices connected to it.

I wanted to know if there is a command (unix) to be able to get some information of a given host (name, brand, whatever) so that I can determine easily which ip address corresponds to which device.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't have DNS set up for your local network, your best bet is probably to use NMap, which can (depending on what switches you pass it, how the hosts are set up, and how lucky you are) tell you the NIC vendor and MAC address, the services running on each host, and possibly even the version of those services and what OS the system is running.

The particular command I would use for this is:

```
nmap -PR -sS -sU -sV -O -T4 192.168.0.0/16
```

Replace `192.168.0.0/16` with the proper CIDR for your network.

The specific options do the following:

- `-PR`: Uses ARP requests instead of ICMP ECHO_REQUEST's to determine what's online.  This is a slight performance optimization (you need to send the ARP request anyway), and will also properly detect hosts that block ICMP ECHO_REQUEST's as online.
- `-sS`: This does the standard TCP SYN scan that NMap uses by default.
- `-sU`: Similar to `-sS`, but for UDP instead of TCP.
- `-sV`: Enables version detection.  This adds a lot of time to the scan, so you can safely exclude it if you don't need this info to figure out what is what.
- `-O`: Enables OS detection.  This uses timing info and other data from the other scans to try and figure out what OS the system is running.  It's actually pretty accurate as long as the remote system has a couple of TCP and UDP ports open.
- `-T4`: This accelerates the scan quite a lot, at the cost of increased network load.  `-T5` will go even faster, but the scanning won't work reliably unless everything on the network is idle.

If you want some more info, I suggest looking at the nmap documentation, it's pretty exhaustive and probably one of the most well documented open-source projects around.

Comment: Oh I see, I've tried it and works (with T3 argument) but it's really slow.. I thought there was a fast method, for instance there's a mobile app called FING which is able to get this information pretty fast (2-5 secs depending on the network size)

Comment: NMap is probably also doing a lot more work than FING.  If you remove `-sV` it will speed things up a lot (service version detection takes a _long_ time).  `-F` will also help, that causes NMap to scan only one tenth of the ports it normally checks.  Part of the other issue is that while NMap does parallelize the scan, it doesn't use broadcast pings (because they aren't reliable), so it is scanning all the hosts on the subnet independently.

Comment: This is very informative, however it still doesn't answer the question: how to get the device's hostname (which is returned for example by Android network scanner apps in a matter of few seconds).